# Stack overflow UI display is strange - what happened?

Tags: support

My Stack Overflow page displays like following.

I have logged out and logged in and also closed the browser and reopened it but still no change:

[image: weird UI]

Comment: @ChrisF yes ..solved..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's the mobile UI.

At some point you must have clicked the "mobile" link in the footer.

If you scroll down you should see a reduced footer with a "full site" link in it.

Click that (there's no hover action) and you'll be returned to the full web interface.